Trying to Make 5 Star Rating in SwiftUI
I'm trying to make a 5 star rating using a rectangle and masking it to the shape of the stars. Everything seems fine when the rectangle is at full width (5 star rating) but when it's anything other than that, the alignment doesn't work.
struct FiveStarRating: View {
    @State private var rating = 0
    var body: some View {
        stars.overlay(alignment: .leading) {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                    .frame(width: CGFloat(rating) / 5 * proxy.size.width)
                    .animation(.bouncy, value: rating)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
                    .mask(stars)
            }
        }
    }

    private var stars: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1...5, id:\.self) { i in
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        rating = i
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}


You can add one more frame modifier to make sure that the overlay takes up the entire space (but is still leading-aligned), while keeping the Rectangle constrained to a certain width:
struct FiveStarRating: View {
    @State private var rating = 0
    var body: some View {
        stars
            .overlay{
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundStyle(.orange)
                    .frame(width: CGFloat(rating) / 5 * proxy.size.width)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // <-- Here
                    .animation(.bouncy, value: rating)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
                    .mask(stars)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var stars: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1...5, id:\.self) { i in
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        rating = i
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

